# How to trim lines in matlab's plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, trim

I'm plotting random lines and one circle as shown in the picture.
So I need to delete lines that located out of the circle and keep that's inside it. Also, if some lines have one point inside the circle and the other point outside the circle then I need to trim the outside part.
How can I do that?
Thank you in advance

I used this code

```
% plotting random lines
X1 = rand (8,8);
Y1 = rand (8,8);
figure
plot (X1,Y1)
hold on
% plotting the circle
R = 0.5;
angle = linspace(0,2*pi,180);
x= Rcos(angle);
y= Rsin(angle);
plot(x,y,'r')
axis equal
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried yourself so far? Please read [ask]

Comment: Hi, I'm not really that expert in matlab I used this code,
% plotting random lines
X1 = rand (8,8);
Y1 = rand (8,8);
figure
plot (X1,Y1)
hold on
 % plotting the circle
 R = 0.5;
 angle = linspace(0,2*pi,180);
 x= R*cos(angle);
 y= R*sin(angle); 
 plot(x,y,'r')
 axis equal

but I don't know how to trim the lines out of the circle

Comment: This code generates the plot. My question was, what have you tried to solve this problem, and how do you fail in doing so??

Comment: Every line is represented by an equation, so loop through them and either discard if it is outside the circle or trim it if needed.

Comment: For lines located outside the circle, it can be done like that. However, for lines which some of them out and some of them inside, then this procedure won't work.

Comment: @LizaSmith Yes it can. You have an equation for the cirlcle, no? And you have an equation for the line, no?

Comment: Hi Anon, yes I got what you mean I will check for intersections between the lines and the circle.